# Joo ReCaptcha & Joomla Registration

Tags: joomla1.5, recaptcha, virtuemart

I have a Joomla/VM site & have installed Joo ReCaptcha.

In the settings of the plugin, I change 'Add to Registration Page?' to yes, but nothing appears.

The Plugin works fine on the conatact & forgot password pages.

The site is Secure Products d00tt c00mm (remove spaces & the such).

I have searched & googled to no avail.

AHIA!!!

Comment: i also want to add the captcha on vm registration page
and i tried to user
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/captcha/13876
but not worked as it worked for joomla registration page like recaptcha does
 for adding it on vm registration page i use google recaptcha on vm registration page manually ...

Comment: you want captcha where on joomla registration page or vm registration page ?

Comment: @Anand...How did you add it manually??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Google recaptcha for virtuemart registration page .

follow step here for adding it manually for vm page
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php

and if you want it on joomla registration page then use recaptcha plugin for that 
and follow the following steps

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_use_Recaptcha_in_Joomla%3F

1)configure your keys their
2)then enable it from global configuration
then it works

Comment: Sorry...This is a Joomla 1.5 site.

Comment: Yes, I would like Captcha for VM Login

Comment: ok then you should go to page of login and do the manual code their

either https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php  
or http://www.phpjabbers.com/captcha-image-verification-php19.html
that would surely help you .
if you like my answer please accept.thanks